# Input fileds in oneline

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, formfield

Could someone help me to have two input fields and a submit button on the same line? I have created sample in jsfiddle. Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/Mndgw/

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="Test1" type="text" class="form-control" id="test1" >
                <input name="Test2" type="text" class="form-control" id="test2" >
                <button name="TestSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>                    
            </div>         
     </div> <!-- col-lg-4 col close -->
    </div> <!-- row close -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Mndgw/1/
In general: in order to place several divs in one line, they should all have a container which has display: inline-block, and a numeric width(px\percent) width, and each one of them should have the css property display:inline-block, along with numeric width(px\precent)
HI I have updated your code, please view the fiddle

```
@import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
.myField{
    width:39%;
    display:inline-block;

}
.mySubmit{
    width:19%;
    display: inline block;
}
.myContainer{
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

-

```
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <div class="form-group myContainer">
                <input name="Test1" type="text" class="form-control myField" id="test1" >
                <input name="Test2" type="text" class="form-control myField" id="test2" >
                <button name="TestSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mySubmit" >Submit</button>                   
            </div>         
     </div> <!-- col-lg-4 col close -->
    </div> <!-- row close -->
```

Comment: Thanks!. Instead explicitly adding more styles, cane we use bootstrap predefined CSS. Casue in my form, later if I added another textfield and Lable they don't look aligned. http://jsfiddle.net/Mndgw/2/.

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't have a class for block \ inline-block display css property, but you can create one and use it along with the bootstrap classes.